# Typescript - Extract all types from Maybe

Tags: typescript

I have a type like:

```
type Maybe<T> = T | null

type Post {
 content: Maybe<{
  id: string;
  title: string;
 }>
}
```

It's generated from the API so I can't update it. I want to create a new type based on the `Post`, but without `Maybe`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

```js
type Maybe<T> = T | null

type Post = {
    content: Maybe<{
        id: string;
        title: string;
    }>
}

type UnMaybe<Obj> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends Maybe<infer T> ? T : Obj[Prop]
}

type Result = UnMaybe<Post>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnXJxW)

Comment: @chrisbajorin thank you very much